# How to avoid an entire call stack being declared MainActor because a low-level function needs it?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

I have an interesting query with regard to @MainActor and strict concurrency checking (-Xfrontend -warn-concurrency -Xfrontend -enable-actor-data-race-checks)

I have functions (Eg, Analytics) that at the lowest level require access to the device screen scale `UIScreen.main.scale` which is isolated to MainActor.  However I would prefer not to have to declare the entire stack of functions above the one that accesses `scale` as requiring MainActor.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have no other options?

How would be the best way to ensure my code only ever calls `UIScreen` once and keeps the result available for next time without manually defining a var and checking if its nil?  Ie is there a kind of computed property that will do this?

Edit: Is there an equivalent of this using MainActor (`MainActor.run` doesn't do the same thing; it seems to block synchronously):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Avoid calling UI components deep down in your code?

Comment: Its perfectly reasonable IMO to want `UIScreen` scale or `UIDevice` userInterfaceIdiom at a low level without needing everything to be on MainActor.  Is there a nice design pattern to avoid it?  I can think of a hacky way to do it, but wondering how others have resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Non-UI code should not rely directly on UIScreen. The scale (for example), should be passed as a parameter, or to actors in their `init`. If the scale changes (which it can, when screens are added or removed), then the new value should be sent to the actor. Or the actor can observe something that publishes the scale when it changes.

The key point is accessing UIScreen from a random thread is not valid for a reason. The scale can in fact change at any time. Reading it from an actor is and should be an async call.

It sounds like you have some kind of Analytics actor. The simplest implementation of this would be to just pass the scale when you create it.

Comment: Thanks @rob 
I'll take that feedback onboard about why it requires to be on main thread - however the question still stands.  There must be a way to put a low-level code block on MainActor and break the link so the entire app doesn't need to be declared MainActor.  Ive discovered a way to do it with DispatchQueue, is there an equivalent way with MainActor?

Comment: `Task { await MainActor.run { ... }}`. Generate an attached or detached Task, and call  `.run`. That's the async-way to kick off an action you don't want to wait for. If you want to wait for the result, just use `await MainActor.run` without the extra Task.